# AWS Tomcat pointing domain name to server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, domain, tomcat, elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS EC2 Elastic Beanstalk (Elastic Load Balancer) instance. I also have a registered domain name with 1&1 Domains.

My AWS load balanacer instance has a domain name:

https://thewhozoo.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

**Question**

How do I get my 1&1 domain:

[thewhozoo.com](http://thewhozoo.com)

to point to the AWS load balancer?

I have tried the `A/AAAA Records`, setting the `IPv4 Address` to my public IP, but this doesn't work because it points directly to the instance, and not the load balancer (`https://thewhozoo.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/`);

Comment: You typically use a CNAME DNS entry. [Guide here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html). You don't use the protocol, just the server name given to you by AWS. What you're trying to use seems to be the application endpoint rather than an ELB. More info [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html).

Comment: Do I need to set up `Route 53` on AWS? (If I do so, I see I can transfer my domain from 1&1 to AWS, but the problem is AWS is that it is much more expensive, i.e. $50/month plus other costs https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/)

Comment: If I don't use `Route 53`, and rather 'use a CNAME record to route queries to your load balancer', does that just redirect the domain name (`www.thewhozoo.com`) to the ELB (`https://thewhozoo.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/`)?  Ie, does it just change the url to `https://thewhozoo.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/`? If this is the case, it's not suitable, because the domain name in the browser url needs to be `www.thewhozoo.com` for SEO and the `https` certificate lets secure traffic on that name.

Comment: You don't need to use R53. You just need to make a DNS CNAME entry at your existing registrar pointing at your ELB domain name. A CNAME isn't a redirect, it's more like an alias, but it's not quite either. You probably need to do some reading to learn DNS, this is generally considered quite simple and it's well documented.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that's the advise I need. I think my simplest solution is to do as you sugggest and use a CNAME on 1&1. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that's the advise I need. I think my simplest solution is to do as you sugggest and use a CNAME on 1&1. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to create a CNAME record on your existing DNS provider, containing the url of your load balancer.

*This just moves my comments to an answer so it can be marked off as complete.*